# What is the use of setting outlier.color = NA in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Whats the use of below statement outlier.color = NA ?? is it to remove outlier from boxplot view??

```
 f<- ggplot(data= Fin, aes(x=Industry,y=Growth,colour=Industry))



 f + geom_jitter() + geom_boxplot(size=2,alpha=0.5,outlier.color = NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

`outlier.color` overrides the default aesthetics used for outlier points.

> ```
> p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
>
> # By default, outlier points match the colour of the box. Use
> # outlier.colour to override
> p + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", outlier.shape = 1)
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JqES.png): http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html#examples

Setting the color to `NA` effectively makes them transparent.

```
p + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA)
```

[image]